# AWS Athena Hive: strip unneeded characters from data in a column

Tags: hive, amazon-athena

I'm a newcomer to Hive and Athena on AWS.  I have data in a table that looks like:

```
_id
type
title
```

An `_id` looks like `{"$oid":"12asdf9"}`.

I have managed to create a query that strips the data of everything but the actual id using `regexp_extract`

I now need to save the results of this query into the `_id` column.

The solution I'm trying out (and I can't get to work) is:

1. Run `regexp_extract` on the `_id` column
2. Select all the other columns I need
3. Dump the results into a new table

My code to do this (see below) returns `line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'create external' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception;`.

I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this.  Thanks!

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sitbi_test_db.combined AS
SELECT unioned._id, unioned.type, unioned.title
FROM (
  SELECT a._id, regexp_extract( a._id, '(?<=oid\"\:\")(.*)(?=\"\})')
  FROM sitbi_test_db.announcements a
  UNION ALL  
) unioned
LOCATION 's3://sitbi-test-mongodb/cleanedAnnouncements/'
```

NOTE: I manually created a new directory `cleanedAnnouncements` in my source S3 bucket, I'm not sure if this is meant to point to the Athena output bucket

Comment: as far as I know, you can not create tables with select statements in athena, they have to be loaded from `S3` so it appears as though you are pointing towards a location in `S3` but not actually loading anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than performing a `CREATE TABLE AS`, you should perform a `CREATE TABLE` statement with RegexSerDe. Below is my attempt at building your table using RegexSerDe.

Note: The below assumes the S3 file lines are in the format `{"$oid":"12asdf9"} type title`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sitbi_test_db.combined (
id STRING,
type STRING,
title STRING
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "input.regex" = "^.*\:\"(.*).*\"\}.*\s(.*).*\s(.*)$"
 ) LOCATION 's3://sitbi-test-mongodb/cleanedAnnouncements/';
```

[Athena docs on RegexSerDe](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/apache.html)

Comment: Thanks tons - I will try this out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly you're using regex when Athena (which uses Presto) can handle json and has a JSON datatype (more info [here](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html) and some [further info on Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html)).

So I think you should be able to do this:

```
SELECT json_extract(_id,'$.$oid') AS _id FROM sitbi_test_db.announcements
```

to retrieve all the nested json id's.  Then you could use [WITH statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html) because Athena doesn't support select's within selects (AFAIK) - they are done using WITH statements instead:

```
WITH dataset AS (SELECT json_extract(_id,'$.$oid') AS id FROM sitbi_test_db.announcements)
SELECT dataset.id FROM dataset
```

However I don't think for this you even would need to do that.  Do modify your previous CTAS statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sitbi_test_db.combined AS
SELECT json_extract(_id,'$.$oid') AS id, type, title
FROM sitbi_test_db.announcements
LOCATION 's3://sitbi-test-mongodb/cleanedAnnouncements/'
```

I also believe that Athena has limitations on column headings (lowercase alpha, numeric + underscore), and according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html), names beginning with an underscore like your `_id` require backticks, so that may also be messing with your queries.  Hope this helps!